# How to upload file which is response of third party API

Tags: go, go-gin

I am new to Go Programming. I need to upload a file which I am getting from a third party API.

I am getting response as a PDF file from third party API. Now I want to upload this PDF file to a folder. I am not understanding how I can upload that PDF file and not getting any reference.

```golang
url := "https://api.xyz.com/v3/files/fcc280cf620204d4bb5dbd6a8cbbbb8fea1a20fc"
client := &http.Client{}
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Failed")
}
req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
req.SetBasicAuth("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "")
resp, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("ERROR")
}
fmt.Println(resp) // here I am getting pdf file
defer resp.Body.Close()
```

Please suggest me some reference or some sample code. I am working on this since last few days to complete this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty simple. First, create and open a file using `os.Create`.

```
out, err := os.Create("filename.pdf")
if err != nil {
    return err
}
defer out.Close()
```

Next, use `io.Copy()` to download the content.

```
_, err = io.Copy(out, resp.Body)
```

You can take a look at [this](https://gophercoding.com/download-a-file/) for reference.

Comment: There are 2 ways of doing this, you can first download the file to local and then upload it, or you can stream it directly. Altough, it depends on the specification of the other request just as you said.

Comment: How can we do using stream? because I am uploading pdf in folder then get that file and do some action and then delete stored pdf after my work done. so if i use stream i do not have to store and delete. is there any reference?

Comment: Well, to be honest I haven't tried that either but ```resp.Body``` is just an array of bytes so if your upload request uses an array of bytes you can directly use this. Since I have never tried this myself I am not sure if this will work

Comment: Okay, I'll try. Thanks lot